# formtastic select menu using an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm trying to populate a [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) select menu using an Array.

#### model

```
PAYMENT_METHODS = %w[creditcard check money-order cash western-union]
```

#### views

```
<%= f.input :payment_methods, :as=>:select, :collection => User::PAYMENT_METHODS%>
```

It works but, this is how it appear now.

```
<select>
<option value="creditcard">creditcard</option>
<option value="western-union">western-union</option>
</select>
```

Instead I want it to look like:

```
<select>
<option value="creditcard">Credit Card</option>
<option value="western-union">Western Union</option>
</select>
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to test it, but I think you can do it this way.

```
%w[Credit\ Card Check Money \Order Cash Western\ Union]
```

From the [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html) docs.

**Updated:**

After reading back through the select examples on the [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) Github page, I believe you can do this. As before, it is untested.

```
 <%= f.input :payment_methods, :as=>:select, :collection => { "Credit Card" => "creditcard", "Check" => "check", "Money Order" => "money-order", "Cash" => "cash" "Western Union" => "western-union" >
```

Comment: Thanks but, I'd like to store the value as `credit-card` in database while showing `Credit Card` as the display name for option item.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you wanted something different for the database. I've updated my answer.